# Sidekiq/redis conflict with websocket_rails: eventmachine not initialized: evma_connect_to_server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, websocket, redis, eventmachine, sidekiq

I am using `sidekiq (2.13.1)` (see dependencies [here](https://rubygems.org/gems/sidekiq/versions/2.13.1)), `websocket-rails (0.6.2)` (see dependencies [here](http://rubygems.org/gems/websocket-rails/versions/0.6.2)) and `redis-semaphore (0.2.1)` (see dependencies [here](http://rubygems.org/gems/redis-semaphore/versions/0.2.1)).

`sidekiq` has been running in my application for a long time, but after having installed `websocket-rails` I am no longer able to perform my sidekiq jobs. They all crash with this stack trace:

```
2013-09-15T13:15:17Z 12682 TID-ouvinq47w INFO: Sidetiq::Clock start
2013-09-15T13:15:19Z 12682 TID-ouvinq47w INFO: Booting Sidekiq 2.13.1 using redis://localhost:6379/0 with options {}
2013-09-15T13:15:19Z 12682 TID-ouvinq47w INFO: Running in ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674) [x86_64-darwin12.4.0]
2013-09-15T13:15:19Z 12682 TID-ouvinq47w INFO: See LICENSE and the LGPL-3.0 for licensing details.
2013-09-15T13:15:19Z 12682 TID-ouvinq47w INFO: Starting processing, hit Ctrl-C to stop
2013-09-15T13:15:20Z 12682 TID-ouvjitprc EvaluationsJob JID-7a108bea6da948aee5f43a99 INFO: start
2013-09-15T13:15:20Z 12682 TID-ouvjitprc EvaluationsJob JID-7a108bea6da948aee5f43a99 INFO: fail: 0.003 sec
2013-09-15T13:15:20Z 12682 TID-ouvjitprc WARN: {"retry"=>false, "queue"=>"default", "class"=>"EvaluationsJob", "args"=>["518f599683c336fb87000003"], "jid"=>"7a108bea6da948aee5f43a99", "enqueued_at"=>1379250920.38564}
2013-09-15T13:15:20Z 12682 TID-ouvjitprc WARN: eventmachine not initialized: evma_connect_to_server
2013-09-15T13:15:20Z 12682 TID-ouvjitprc WARN: /Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/eventmachine-1.0.3/lib/eventmachine.rb:664:in `connect_server'
/Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/eventmachine-1.0.3/lib/eventmachine.rb:664:in `bind_connect'
/Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/eventmachine-1.0.3/lib/eventmachine.rb:640:in `connect'
/Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/redis-3.0.4/lib/redis/connection/synchrony.rb:72:in `connect'
/Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/redis-3.0.4/lib/redis/client.rb:271:in `establish_connection'
/Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/redis-3.0.4/lib/redis/client.rb:69:in `connect'
/Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/redis-3.0.4/lib/redis/client.rb:290:in `ensure_connected'
/Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/redis-3.0.4/lib/redis/client.rb:177:in `block in process'
/Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/redis-3.0.4/lib/redis/client.rb:256:in `logging'
/Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/redis-3.0.4/lib/redis/client.rb:176:in `process'
/Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/redis-3.0.4/lib/redis/client.rb:84:in `call'
/Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/redis-3.0.4/lib/redis.rb:870:in `block in getset'
/Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/redis-3.0.4/lib/redis.rb:36:in `block in synchronize'
/Users/john/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/redis-3.0.4/lib/redis.rb:36:in `synchronize'
/Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/redis-3.0.4/lib/redis.rb:869:in `getset'
/Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/redis-semaphore-0.2.1/lib/redis/semaphore.rb:26:in `exists_or_create!'
/Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/redis-semaphore-0.2.1/lib/redis/semaphore.rb:48:in `lock'
/Users/john/my_app/app/jobs/evaluations_job.rb:9:in `perform'
/Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sidekiq-2.13.1/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:48:in `block (3 levels) in process'
/Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sidekiq-2.13.1/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:115:in `call'
/Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sidekiq-2.13.1/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:115:in `block in invoke'
/Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sidekiq-failures-0.2.1/lib/sidekiq/failures/middleware.rb:10:in `call'
/Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sidekiq-2.13.1/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:117:in `block in invoke'
/Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sidetiq-0.3.6/lib/sidetiq/middleware.rb:13:in `call'
/Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sidekiq-2.13.1/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:117:in `block in invoke'
/Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sidekiq-2.13.1/lib/sidekiq/middleware/server/active_record.rb:6:in `call'
/Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sidekiq-2.13.1/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:117:in `block in invoke'
/Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sidekiq-2.13.1/lib/sidekiq/middleware/server/retry_jobs.rb:62:in `call'
/Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sidekiq-2.13.1/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:117:in `block in invoke'
/Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sidekiq-2.13.1/lib/sidekiq/middleware/server/logging.rb:11:in `block in call'
/Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sidekiq-2.13.1/lib/sidekiq/logging.rb:22:in `with_context'
/Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sidekiq-2.13.1/lib/sidekiq/middleware/server/logging.rb:7:in `call'
/Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sidekiq-2.13.1/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:117:in `block in invoke'
/Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sidekiq-2.13.1/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:120:in `call'
/Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sidekiq-2.13.1/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:120:in `invoke'
/Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sidekiq-2.13.1/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:47:in `block (2 levels) in process'
/Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sidekiq-2.13.1/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:102:in `stats'
/Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sidekiq-2.13.1/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:46:in `block in process'
/Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sidekiq-2.13.1/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:83:in `do_defer'
/Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sidekiq-2.13.1/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:37:in `process'
/Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/celluloid-0.14.1/lib/celluloid/calls.rb:25:in `public_send'
/Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/celluloid-0.14.1/lib/celluloid/calls.rb:25:in `dispatch'
/Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/celluloid-0.14.1/lib/celluloid/calls.rb:125:in `dispatch'
/Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/celluloid-0.14.1/lib/celluloid/actor.rb:326:in `block in handle_message'
/Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/celluloid-0.14.1/lib/celluloid/tasks.rb:42:in `block in initialize'
```

My issue is related to [this Github issue](https://github.com/websocket-rails/websocket-rails/issues/37), but my version is `websocket-rails (0.6.2)`, which is higher than the `websocket-rails (0.2.1)` that was supposed to deal with this issue.

The stack trace refers to my sidekiq job here:

```
## jobs/evaluations_job.rb

class EvaluationsJob
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  sidekiq_options :retry => false

  def perform(user_id)
    s = Redis::Semaphore.new("perform_evaluations_for_#{user_id}".to_sym, redis: NonBlockingRedis.new(connection: "localhost"))

    if s.lock(-1)  # => THIS IS evaluations_job.rb:9 WHERE IT ALL BREAKS...
      ...
    end
  end
end
```

I am using the standard settings for both `sidekiq` and `websocket-rails`, but as I am not quite sure what is the root of this issue I have included this `sidetiq` config file in my question (I am using a `sidetiq` initiated job to start all other jobs):

```
## config/initializers/sidetiq.rb

Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
  require 'non_blocking_redis'
  Sidetiq::Clock.start!
end
```

Answer (score 5):

I believe this might be the solution to fix your problem

https://github.com/websocket-rails/websocket-rails/issues/29

```
$redis = Redis.new(:host => host, :port => port, :driver => :hiredis)
```

Comment: Why do you believe that?  Explanations are often nice (although, to be fair, I don't know `ruby` very well :)

Comment: The problem was that the redis gem was expecting eventmachine to be around so it could use it as an interface to redis. By telling it that you want to use hiredis as the underlying driver instead you get around the problem.